# Xcode: How can I slide left/right between UIViews?

Tags: uiview, xcode4

I want the easiest way to implement a sliding right/left gesture between multiple UIViews like AngryBirds levels as in the below screenshot

[image: AngryBirds Levels Screenshot]

Comment: UIPageControl - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to not use a slide gesture, instead use a `UIScrollView` with a `contentSize.width` smaller than its `frame.size.width` (to show the previous/next pages), with `pagingEnabled = YES` and `clipsToBounds = NO`.